# How to get values from object and assign them to consts

Tags: reactjs

So I'm pulling some data from my DB and it comes out in the form of an object. I'd like to take this object and turn it into separate constants. This is the object
(sorry for link, I dont have enough rep to post images)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjWQs.png

How can I take values out from the object and assign them to constants.  I want to get the value of the field 'address' which is the apartment's address and assign it to a const called rent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for this very easily:

```
const { rent: address, ownerEmail, otherProperty1, otherProperty2 } = yourObject;
console.log(rent); //The address
```

Comment: arr.map( arr => <div>{arr.flexibility}</div> this is the only access I have. I'm having a tough time Destructuring.

Comment: The code is extremely long and intertwined. I think my problem is, that its not waiting for the fetch to finish therefore its trying to use an undefined object. Is there a way to fix this? To wait for the fetch to finish

Comment: You can use async/await or chain your fetch call promise with `.then((response) => { ... })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring. So, let's say you only want the `id` from the object. You could do something like the following:

```
const { id } = await fetchMyData();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the object properties like,

1.

```
const {ac, address} = yourObject;
```

2.

```
const ac = yourObject.ac;
const address = yourObject.address;
```

Hope this can help!